# Well-known estimate for $L(s,\chi)$ for $\sigma=\text{Re}s\geq 1/2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, multiplicative-number-theory

This is a very short question.

Let $s=\sigma+it$ be a complex number with $\sigma \geq 1/2$.

In the paper 'Jutila, Matti. "On the Mean Value of $L(1/2, \chi)$ FW Real Characters." Analysis 1.2 (1981): 149-161.', p.156, the author estimates $|L(s,\chi)| \ll (q(|t|+1))^{1/4}$, where $q$ is a modulus of the character $\chi$. He said that it is a well-known estimate.

I want to find the reference for this 'well-known' estimate, but I couldn't. Could you let me know where I can find about it?

--

Lucia pointed out that this is a convexity bound for $L$-function. The follwoing statements is in 119p, Thm 5.23 of 'Iwaniec, Henryk, and Emmanuel Kowalski. Analytic number theory. Vol. 53. American Mathematical Soc., 2004.'.

> **Theorem** Let $\chi$ modulo $q$ be a primitive Dirichlet character. We have
>   $$
> L(s,\chi) \ll (q|s|)^{1/4}
> $$
>   for $\sigma=1/2$.

This is very similar to the estimation in this question. Howerver, the theorem states for only critical line, but we need to treat the sector $\sigma \geq 1/2$. How can I extend this theorem to the sector $\sigma \geq 1/2$?

Comment: This is the convexity bound for L--functions.  For example, see the Chapter in Iwaniec--Kowalski on $L$--functions.  (Chapter 11 if I remember correctly).

Comment: Lucia // Okay. I'm gonna check it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You get this bound for the whole region from the critical line by the Phragmen-Lindelhof principle

Comment: Loughran // Thank you for the answer. I'll try it.